# Operators with time format

Tags: php, operators, subtitle, time-format

I have for example `00:09:33.485` this time for movie or episode and i want to add 30 secs or 5 mins , so how to make it to be like this `00:09:33.485 + 00:05:30.124 = 00:15:03.609` or like this `00:09:33.485 - 00:05:30.124 = 00:04:03.361`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i edited sjagr answer and this is for minus :

```
$time = '00:09:33.485';
$add = '00:05:30.124';

$timeMs = explode('.', $time);
$addMs = explode('.', $add);

$sumMs = $timeMs[1] - $addMs[1];
$timeSplit = explode(':', $timeMs[0]);
$addSplit = explode(':', $addMs[0]);

if ($sumMs < 0) {
    $timeSplit[2] -= 1;
    $sumMs = $sumMs + 1000;
}
$sumMs = str_pad($sumMs, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$i = 2;
while ($i >= 0) {
    $timeSplit[$i] -= $addSplit[$i];
    if ($i > 0 && $timeSplit[$i] < 0) {
        $timeSplit[$i - 1] -= 1;
        $timeSplit[$i] = $timeSplit[$i] + 60;
    }
    $timeSplit[$i] = str_pad($timeSplit[$i], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $i--;
}

$time = implode(':', $timeSplit);
$time = $time . '.' . $sumMs;

echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard time format combined with the `DateTime` class to achieve proper time format and mathematics, but if you insist on using this format...

```
$time = '00:09:33.485';
$add = '00:05:30.124';

$timeMs = explode('.', $time);
$addMs = explode('.', $add);

$sumMs = $timeMs[1] + $addMs[1];
$timeSplit = explode(':', $timeMs[0]);
$addSplit = explode(':', $addMs[0]);

if ($sumMs > 1000) {
    $timeSplit[2] += 1;
    $sumMs = $sumMs - 1000;
}
$sumMs = str_pad($sumMs, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$i = 2;
while ($i >= 0) {
    $timeSplit[$i] += $addSplit[$i];
    if ($i > 0 && $timeSplit[$i] > 59) {
        $timeSplit[$i - 1] += 1;
        $timeSplit[$i] = $timeSplit[$i] - 60;
    }
    $timeSplit[$i] = str_pad($timeSplit[$i], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $i--;
}

$time = implode(':', $timeSplit);
$time = $time . '.' . $sumMs;

echo $time; // Returns 00:15:03.609 - note that there's no handling for 24+ hours
```

This is a lot of work, so again you really should [check out the docs on the `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), specifically [the `add()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: i need it to work on `+` and `-` too , this code work on `-`?

Comment: @AdamMo. Addition only, because that's what you asked for in the scope of your question.

Comment: @AdamMo. See my edit, specifically `while ($i >= 0) {` instead of `while ($i > 0) {`

Comment: @AdamMo. `if ($i > 0 && $timeSplit[$i] > 59) {` is the latest fix. Again you do realize that all of this has been built with `DateTime` if you just decided to accept a standard DateTime format?

Comment: i want this format for subtitles, plz can you write another code for `-`? thank you

Comment: @AdamMo. I've answered your original question within the scope of what you've asked. You should be able to figure out the inverse strategy (hint... flip everything around, `+` becomes `-`, `>` becomes `<`, `--` becomes `++`...) - writing this entire snippet of code was a handout but was more meant for you to understand how much work is involved instead of using the `DateTime` class, perhaps with `format()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which unfortunately only works with full seconds but no milliseconds:

```
<?php
function addtime($t1, $t2)
{
  $d = date_create("1970-01-01 $t1");
  list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $t2);
  date_add($d, new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$m}M{$s}S"));
  return date('H:i:s', $d->getTimestamp());
}

print addtime('00:09:33', '00:05:30');
?>
```

For substraction of time use date_sub() instead of date_add().

**EDIT**: Here the same function including milliseconds:

```
function addtime($t1, $t2)
{
  list($t1, $ms1) = explode('.', $t1);
  $d = date_create("1970-01-01 $t1");
  list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $t2);
  list($s, $ms2) = explode('.', $s);

  date_add($d, new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$m}M{$s}S"));
  $ts = $d->getTimestamp();

  $ms = $ms1 + $ms2;
  if($ms >= 1000) { $ms -= 1000; $ts++; }

  return date('H:i:s', $ts) . ".$ms";
}

print addtime('00:09:33.485', '00:05:30.124');
```